# NumPy to GeoTiff for use with Gdal

Tags: python, raster, gdal, numpy

I have a few NumPy arrays: lat, lon, and 6 data bands. I'd like to convert these to GeoTiff and then apply the gdalwarp function, based on a specific projection, to each band.

Is there a standard way to do this in Python?

Comment: possible dublicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file

Comment: Possible, yes. A major difference is that my lat/lon resolutions aren't always uniform. Defining the geotransform is the key, I think.

Comment: So they don't form a complete grid?  In this case you will either have to interpolate a surface from the observations, or be left with missing values.  Any preference? Can you better characterize the presence of lat/lon observations for us?

Comment: To give you more context: I have a series of HDF5 files, with swath grided data and lat/lon values. The coordinate description is " geodetic lat/lon of the center of each 1 km cell."  I need to first apply some flagging and filtering operations to the data, then re-project to EPSG:6933. I was making virtual rasters (.vrt files) then using gdalwarp to do all this. But because of the flagging operations, things got a bit complicated, hence numpy arrays. The HDF5 don't have an specific geolocation meta data either. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Can be done fairly easy. First, create the dataset:

```
drv = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
ds = drv.Create("name.tif", width, height, 6, gdal.GDT_Float32)
```

You then need to set the geotransform using `ds.SetGeoTransform` where the argument is a six element tuple: `(upper_left_x, x_resolution, x_skew, upper_left_y, y_skew, y_resolution)`

Set the projection using `ds.SetProjection`, argument is the way string, then 
Write the array for the first band:

```
ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr)
```

That should be enough to get you going. If the purpose is just to reproject the data, then you could look at using an in memory dataset

Comment: Make sure to use ds.SetGeoTransform instead of ds.SetGeotransform