# Concatenate two rasters into a single raster with multiple bands GDAL

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

Maybe I am not asking the question with the appropriate English words, but I would like to basically concatenate multi bands rasters (two or more) into a single raster with all the bands intact. The rasters have the same number of bands (4), and have all the same extent.

I can't find the proper tool in QGIS or either in GDAL. I first thought merge could do the job but it ends up with 4 bands having the average value of the 3rd band of each file for instance (for the 3rd band).

I can either use QGIS, GDAL with python, or directly GDAL in the terminal - all solutions are welcome.

Comment: Do the images overlap? Can you illustrate what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Binx the images overlap, they have exactly the same extent. It's just monthly composites of a Region of interest and I want to have only one file with all the information (all the bands).

Comment: So you would want 8 bands on one image? How would you decide how to view the data? Which band would have priority over the other?

Comment: @Binx it's to train a deep-learning model, it's not for visualisation purpose

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend using numpy then. Maybe look at [numpy.stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)

Comment: Ok thank you. I was also thinking about that but secretly hoping for a hidden tool in GDAL or QGIS. I'll try with OTB because it looks like what I am looking for!

Comment: Most data that is feed into ML tasks are going to be using numpy anyways, but if you have to have a geotiff, then you could use look at [this method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198013/numpy-to-geotiff-for-use-with-gdal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use OTB which is executable from QGIS if you wish (or from the command prompt). The ConcatenateImage function seems to fit your need (https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_ConcatenateImages.html)