# error with python gdal

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I tried to do this code [Array to Raster image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file) but there was the following error

```
ERROR 4: Unable to open myraster.tif to obtain file list.
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.
Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the
directory containing EPSG csv files.
```

this is the code

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdal_array
from osgeo import osr
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

array = np.array(( (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4),
                   (0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
                   (0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6),
                   (0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7),
                   (0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8) ))
# My image array      
lat = np.array(( (10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                 ( 9.5,  9.5,  9.5,  9.5),
                 ( 9.0,  9.0,  9.0,  9.0),
                 ( 8.5,  8.5,  8.5,  8.5),
                 ( 8.0,  8.0,  8.0,  8.0) ))
lon = np.array(( (20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5),
                 (20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5),
                 (20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5),
                 (20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5),
                 (20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5) ))
# For each pixel I know it's latitude and longitude.
# As you'll see below you only really need the coordinates of
# one corner, and the resolution of the file.

xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = [lon.min(),lat.min(),lon.max(),lat.max()]
nrows,ncols = np.shape(array)
xres = (xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres = (ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres)   
# That's (top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation (0 if North is up), 
#         top left y, rotation (0 if North is up), n-s pixel resolution)
# I don't know why rotation is in twice???

output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('myraster.tif',ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)  # Open the file
output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)  # Specify its coordinates
srs = osr.SpatialReference()                 # Establish its coordinate encoding
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)                     # This one specifies WGS84 lat long.
                                             # Anyone know how to specify the 
                                             # IAU2000:49900 Mars encoding?
output_raster.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )   # Exports the coordinate system 
                                                   # to the file
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)   # Writes my array to the raster
```

Comment: What is the code that you ran to receive that output?  You have a link but I think it is unfair on potential answerers to be required to follow it to try and synthesize your question.

Comment: i use the code that is at the link if you click at "Array to Raster image" i will put the code now

Comment: Did you cd (os.chdir(path)) into the directory that myraster.tif is in?

Comment: I use canopy to do the code so i just run it. do i have to create the file first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my system, your code works well. It only needs this line:

```
output_raster = None
```

at the bottom.

After running it at the Python Console of QGIS, this is the result visualized at Map Canvas:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

I **copy/paste** your code in a text file (gdal_error.py) and, there were modified/added the lines into red rectangles (see next image). As you can see, it works perfectly in a QGIS 2.14-0-Essen (Windows system).

[image]

Comment: what line did you change?

Comment: I added that line at the bottom of code.

Comment: To add more info: That is a common GDAL Python Gotcha. [An object needs to be dereferenced to be written to disk](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Savingandclosingdatasetsdatasources)

Comment: i ran it as a script and python console on QGIS and this is the error


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/manwlas/appdata/local/temp/tmpuy4zqn.py", line 37, in <module>
    output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)  # Specify its coordinates
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'


i have 2.14 Qgis and i work from windows. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: @Μανώλης Παναγιωτάκης Please, see my editing note.