# Python surface plot in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, matplotlib, surface

I'm new in QGIS and I’m having some troubles. I have produced a surface plot in python and I would like to import it in QGIS but I don't know how do that, can anyone help me?

P.S. I also have the long lat coordinates of the plot for the geo referencing

Comment: You need to add more details. Your data is in what format? Numpy Array? Add a reproducable code snippet.

Comment: Hi BERA, thank you for the answer. I have added the code and the result but i can't upload the csv file. Anyway I also have the long lat coordinates of every point.

Comment: @BERA maybe i can add xconv, yconv and zconv values if you think that may be usefull

Comment: Do you want to turn it into raster or vector data in QGIS? What is your next step

Comment: @BERA Maybe a raster data is better

Comment: [Writing numpy array to raster file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file)

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand how I could do the rastering of my 3D surface plot

Answer (score 1):

Using [Writing numpy array to raster file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file) as suggested by BERA is the easiest way

With one of my examples

Matplotlib 2D:

[image]

Matplotlib 3D (with `def axisEqual3D(ax)` in [set matplotlib 3d plot aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19248731)):

```
ax.plot_surface(xconv, yconv, zconv, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='gist_earth',antialiased=True)
ax.view_init(60,-160)
axisEqual3D(ax)
```

[image]

Convert it into an [ASCII Raster](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/java/Gp_ToolRef/Spatial_Analyst_Tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm)

```
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = [xconv,.min(),yconv.min(),xconv.max(),yconv.max()]
nrows,ncols = np.shape(zconv)
xres = (xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres = (ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres)  
# creation of the raster file 
header = "ncols     %s\n" % ncols
header += "nrows    %s\n" % nrows
header += "xllcorner %s\n" % geotransform[0]
header += "yllcorner %s\n" % geotransform[3]
header += "dx  %s\n" % geotransform[1]
header += "dy  %s\n" % geotransform[5]
header += "NODATA_value -9999\n"
with  open("grid.asc", "w") as f:
  f.write(header)
  np.savetxt(f,zconv, fmt="%1.2f")
```

grid.asc content

ncols     100
nrows    100
xllcorner 251215.52097430476
yllcorner 46722.44250503713
dx  11.230954009630368
dy  -8.647123208649791
NODATA_value -9999
395.37 395.23 395.10 ...

Result in QGIS:

[image]

But you can also use [osgeo.gdal](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) ([Writing Numpy array to raster file (tif) returns a trivial black square](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232309)) or [rasterio](https://pypi.org/project/rasterio/) ([Lesson 1. Export Numpy Arrays to Geotiff Format Using Rasterio and Python](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics-python/multispectral-remote-sensing-in-python/export-numpy-array-to-geotiff-in-python/))