# GDAL, python: How to create a GDAL dataset object from a numpy array

Tags: python, gdal, opencv

I am working on a program that uses both OpenCV and GDAL to perform different tasks. OpenCV stores its images as `numpy` arrays. I would like to be able to go directly from this `numpy` array to a dataset object without having to save the image to the file system and then reopen it again in GDAL. Right now, I have to do this for each image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

img = cv2.imread("image.png", flags=-1)
# modify the image
cv2.imwrite("output.png", img)
ds = gdal.Open("output.png")
# do stuff with GDAL
```

The issue is that the `cv2.imwrite` step is very time consuming, especially since I'm doing it for a lot of images.

My question is this: is there a way to get a dataset from a numpy array directly?

Something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

img = cv2.imread("image.png", flags=-1)
# modify the image
ds = gdal.datasetFromArray(img)
# do stuff with GDAL
```

Comment: A lot of this depends on what you understand as "do stuff with GDAL". Are you reprojecting the data or something similar? You you can create a GDAL dataset, do your manipulations and in the end write the array into it. See for instance: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `gdal_array.OpenArray()` function, where `ds` is a GDAL dataset:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdal_array

img = cv2.imread("image.png", flags=-1)
# modify the image
ds = gdal_array.OpenArray(img)
```