# Rotating raster cells with QGIS GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis-3

I've written a `PyQGIS` script based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file/37431#37431) to the following question:

- [Writing numpy array to raster file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file/)

My data shows up at the correct, expected location but the raster cells, which are 25m x 25m squares, are still X/Y aligned when I would like them to be rotated as well (aligned with the red polygon limit, not the X/Y axis).

Is there a way to do this with `QGIS` / `PyQGIS` / `GDAL` ?

[image]