# Open a numpy array as a GDAL raster in memory

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

I have a numpy array which I would like to open as a raster in GDAL. Currently the only way I can find to do this is to save the raster as an image to the file system and then open it again. I was hoping that there would be a way that I could just create an in-memory raster from a numpy array and then set its transformation and coordinate system manually.

The closest thing I can find is here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37431/48798

And came up with this solution:

```
        nrows, ncols = self.paths_array.shape

        # Explanation for this mess: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/migrating-to-v1.html
        top_left = (self.ref_img.meta["transform"][2], self.ref_img.meta["transform"][5])
        geotransform = (self.ref_img.meta["transform"][2],
                        self.ref_img.meta["transform"][0],
                        self.ref_img.meta["transform"][1],
                        self.ref_img.meta["transform"][5],
                        self.ref_img.meta["transform"][3],
                        self.ref_img.meta["transform"][4])

        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
        raster = driver.Create("myraster", ncols, nrows, 1, gdal.GDT_Int16)
        raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
        srs = osr.SpatialReference()
        srs.ImportFromEPSG(self.srid)  # My SRID
        raster.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
        raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(self.paths_array) # My Numpy array with data
```

By the way, I realize that it is sort of odd that I am taking the result of a rasterio raster and turning it into a gdal raster. The reason for this is that there is a very good algorithm that we found that is written using the Python GDAL bindings, and so we have to switch from rasterio to pure GDAL for this part

But it seems to be written for using the `GTiff` driver, which will create the file on disk. I thought I could avoid this by using the [Memory driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/memory.html):

```
    nrows, ncols = self.paths_array.shape

    # Explanation for this mess: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/migrating-to-v1.html
    top_left = (self.ref_img.meta["transform"][2], self.ref_img.meta["transform"][5])
    geotransform = (self.ref_img.meta["transform"][2],
                    self.ref_img.meta["transform"][0],
                    self.ref_img.meta["transform"][1],
                    self.ref_img.meta["transform"][5],
                    self.ref_img.meta["transform"][3],
                    self.ref_img.meta["transform"][4])

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("Memory")
    raster = driver.Create("myraster", ncols, nrows, 1, gdal.GDT_Int16)
    raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(self.srid)
    raster.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
    raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(self.paths_array)
```

However, no luck. When I use the `Memory` as input to `gdal.GetDriverByName()`, then the result of `driver.Create("myraster", ncols, nrows, 1, gdal.GDT_Int16)` is `None`.

Comment: When you use the `MEM` raster format, what you get at the end is a pointer to an open GDAL dataset, in effect what you get from `gdal.Open()`.

Comment: Thanks, Jose, I was posting an answer just as you commented, if you want to post that as an answer I will accept that one instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out it was a rather simple goof. `Memory` is the keyword for an in-memory **vector** dataset, while `MEM` is the keyword for an in-memory **raster** dataset. I even linked the page for vector datasets in my question, the correct link is here:

https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mem.html

Replacing `Memory` with `MEM` works.