# Creating raster with same size as DTM raster containing certain percentage of zeros and ones using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, create

I've got a DTM and would like to add 1m to a percentage of the points, so I thought of creating a new raster containing either zeros or 1m and add the two raster together.
I didn't find any tools that could do it on SAGA or GRASS.

Do you know a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a numpy Array using [random choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vywdx.jpg), [convert to a ascii raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file) then add to your dtm using raster calculator:

```
import numpy as np

proportion_1 = 0.1 #Adjust
outfile = r'C:\folder\arr.asc' #Adjust path

rl = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('DSM')[0] #Adjust to match your raster layer name
    
e = rl.extent()

h = rl.height()
w = rl.width()
xres = rl.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()

arr = np.random.choice(2, (w,h), p=[1-proportion_1,proportion_1])

with open(outfile,'w') as file:
    header= ['ncols {}'.format(h),
             'nrows {}'.format(w), 
             'xllcorner {}'.format(e.xMinimum()), 
             'yllcorner {}'.format(e.yMinimum()), 
             'cellsize {}'.format(xres), 
             'nodata_value -9999']
    for row in header:
        file.write(row+'\n')
    for row in arr.tolist():
        file.write(' '.join([str(val) for val in row]))
```

Then add them together using raster calculator.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much ! I'm going to try it today !